# How to save/get a rotation from Hololens achor?

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, hololens

I'm using anchor in my application to be the "center of the world" instead of hololens be the "center of the world". I instantiate a cube and turn this my reference to display my 3d objects.

I can get the position normally, but the rotation not. Always when I change of scene and open it again, the position reference of cube is ok. My 3d objects get the position reference and is be displayed ok, but the rotation is come from hololens. If I rotate my head (hololens), the 3d object get this "rotation" and is changed, but I want get the rotation of my cube anchor.

This is my code:

```
//Instantiate the cube
 AnchorController anchorController = anchorManager.GetComponent<AnchorController>();    
 referenceGameObject = GameObject.Find("Cube");    
 referenceGameObject = anchorController.instance;

 //Getting the position and rotation of cube
 Vector3 referencePosition = referenceGameObject.transform.position;
 Quaternion referenceRotation = referenceGameObject.transform.rotation;

 //Instantiate a 3d object and inside her I instantiate my 3d objects     
 GameObject parent = new GameObject("Obj3D");
 Quaternion originalRot = parent.transform.rotation;

 //step.anchorX/Y/Z is a coordinates that came from json file, are running perfectly.
 //Here I get the position reference of my cube, works perfectly.

 parent = Instantiate(parent, referencePosition, referenceRotation);
 parent.transform.position = referencePosition;
 parent.transform.position = parent.transform.position + (referenceGameObject.transform.right * step.anchorX);
 parent.transform.position = parent.transform.position + (referenceGameObject.transform.forward * step.anchorY);
 parent.transform.position = parent.transform.position + (referenceGameObject.transform.up * step.anchorZ);

 //Here I'm getting the reference rotation of my cube and insert a rotation of my cube  
 parent.transform.Rotate(referenceRotation.eulerAngles.x, referenceRotation.eulerAngles.y, referenceRotation.eulerAngles.z); 

 //Here is my 3d objects 
 childObject = Instantiate(SetPrefab(step), parent.transform);
 childObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
 object3d = parent;

 if (step.HLScaleX != 0f && step.HLScaleY != 0f && step.HLScaleZ != 0f){
     object3d.transform.localScale = new Vector3(step.HLScaleX, step.HLScaleY, step.HLScaleZ);
 }

 object3d.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(step.HLRotationX, step.HLRotationY, step.HLRotationZ));
```

In resume,

How I can save/get the rotation of my anchor in Hololens?

Answer (score 0):

Try using local parameters.

I wrote code where I use gestures to move/rotate/scale the object.

when the gesture is recognized and OnManipulationStarted is called I save the local parameters.

```
position = ObjectM.transform.localPosition;
rotation = ObjectM.transform.localRotation;
scale = ObjectM.transform.localScale;
```

Then OnManipulationUpdated is called and depending on mode I update the parameters.
Moving

```
transform.localPosition = positionCache + Vector3.up * delta.y * MOVE_FACTOR;
```

Rotating

```
transform.localRotation = rotationCache;
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * delta.x * ROTATE_FACTOR);
```

Scaling requires a bit more code to make up for negative delta. Delta is the gesture change recognized in ManipulationEventData. For more information about gesture manipulation I recommend to check [mixedrealitytoolkit Input Section](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Input/README.md).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to make your cube the "Center of your world" then you should look at Unity's Transform.InverseTransformPoint and Transform.InverseTransformDirection as well as the opposites of these methods Transform.TransformPoint/Direction.

All you need is a reference to your anchor's transform and a position/direction that you want to pass in.

`transform.position = AnchorTransform.InverseTransformPoint(new Vector3(0,0,1));`

You can also pass in three floats instead if you don't want to pass in a Vector3.

What this does is takes the anchor's position and puts your new position 1 unit away in the z direction. The InverseTransformPoint takes a world position and converts it to a local position for your object.

The same can be done for rotations by doing something like:

`transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(AnchorTransform.InverseTransformDirection(1,0,0);`